# Jquery populate second select item with options greater than first select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to make a simple drop down select for time selection and am stumbling on populating the second list with the options from the first list. I am trying to make a start and end top drop down. So first select has all available times and the second select would have only times available after the first selects start time. I have been able to get it work with simple validation however this leaves the second list with all of the time periods in a day and seems clunky. I want to eliminate the validation and simply provide only available answers in the second select. Right now the code I have been using simply copies the first selected to second. I have been trying to add a greater than selected somehow but just doesn't work.

.html

```
<select class="form-control timepicker required" id="firstTime" >
    <option value="700">7:00am</option><option value="715">7:15am</option><option value="730">7:30am</option><option value="745">7:45am</option>
    <option value="800">8:00am</option><option value="815">8:15am</option><option value="830">8:30am</option><option value="845">8:45am</option>
    <option value="900">9:00am</option><option value="915">9:15am</option><option value="930">9:30am</option><option value="945">9:45am</option>
    <option value="1000">10:00am</option><option value="1015">10:15am</option><option value="1030">10:30am</option><option value="1045">10:45am</option>
    <option value="1100">11:00am</option><option value="1115">11:15am</option><option value="1130">11:30am</option><option value="1145">11:45am</option>
    <option value="1200">12:00pm</option><option value="1215">12:15pm</option><option value="1230">12:30pm</option><option value="1245">12:45pm</option>
    <option value="1300">1:00pm</option><option value="1315">1:15pm</option><option value="1330">1:30pm</option><option value="1345">1:45pm</option>
    <option value="1400">2:00pm</option><option value="1415">2:15pm</option><option value="1430">2:30pm</option><option value="1445">2:45pm</option>
    <option value="1500">3:00pm</option><option value="1515">3:15pm</option><option value="1530">3:30pm</option><option value="1545">3:45pm</option>
    <option value="1600">4:00pm</option><option value="1615">4:15pm</option><option value="1630">4:30pm</option><option value="1645">4:45pm</option>
    <option value="1700">5:00pm</option><option value="1715">5:15pm</option><option value="1730">5:30pm</option><option value="1745">5:45pm</option>
    <option value="1800">6:00pm</option><option value="1815">6:15pm</option><option value="1830">6:30pm</option><option value="1845">6:45pm</option>
    <option value="1900">7:00pm</option><option value="1915">7:15pm</option><option value="1930">7:30pm</option><option value="1945">7:45pm</option>
    <option value="2000">8:00pm</option><option value="2015">8:15pm</option><option value="2030">8:30pm</option><option value="2045">8:45pm</option>
    <option value="2100">9:00pm</option><option value="2115">9:15pm</option><option value="2130">9:30pm</option><option value="2145">9:45pm</option>

</select>
```

.js

```
$('.timepicker').change(function() {
            $('.timepicker').find('option:selected')
            .clone().appendTo('.timepicker2');
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think nextAll might be what you want, to select all subsequent siblings of a selected element. e.g.

```
$('.timepicker').find('option:selected').nextAll()
.clone().appendTo('.timepicker2');
```

Comment: Thank you. I new I was missing a simple jquery call. Is this method cross browser acceptable. As well I have added `$('.timepicker2').empty();` before that to clear the second select if first is repicked.

Comment: No probs. Looking at the jquery bug tracker, it looks like this should be pretty consistent across browsers (although maybe not IE7...!)http://bugs.jquery.com/search?q=nextall&go=&ticket=on

Comment: One more question. I plan on using moment.js for user friendly times/dates on my site. Should i be using a different value for each time period. Or do you think the simple HHMM time structure works fine

Comment: I've not used moment.js before, but I believe it is pretty flexible. I think HHMM will probably be fine, as I would imagine that would be a standard format you could pass in. Might be safest to set values of the options in HHMM though rather than HMM, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you want to do this:

```
$('.timepicker').change(function() {
    $(".timepicker2").empty();
    $('.timepicker').find('option:selected').clone().appendTo('.timepicker2');

    //
    if($('.timepicker').find('option:selected').next()){
        $('.timepicker').find('option:selected').nextAll().clone().appendTo('.timepicker2');
    }
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/8ebZe/1/